# Calling execlp() using parsed user input

Tags: c, operating-system, exec, fork, posix

I am working on a homework assignment for a class where I have to write a program that acts as a shell. The requirements are to use the `fork()` and `execlp()` system calls.

For the program, a shell command is obtained from the user at run time and I have to parse this.

I have looked online and found numerous suggestions to use `execvp()` because we do not know the number of arguments that a user may provide. However I am required to use `execlp()`.

Let's say for example the user input was `cp Picture1.jpg Picture2.jpg`. The call to the `execlp()` function would look like `execlp("cp", "cp", "Picture1.jpg", "Picture2.jpg", NULL);`

My question is how would I call this method without hardcoding? For example the user input may have 2 arguments, or 3 arguments. Is there a data type where I can pass in a variable to `execlp()`? The main problem I am having is calling the `execlp()` system call with the user's input.

Comment: another braindead requirement. The only option I see is to define a maximum number of arguments and call like `execlp(cmd, cmd, arg[0], arg[1], ..., arg[n])`, making sure the first unused argument is `(char *)0`.

Comment: You can't call `execlp` (or any variadic function) without knowing the number of arguments when you write the program.

Comment: It sounds like execvp() is what you want. I suggest looking at the man page for these functions.

Comment: As I stated earlier, `execlp()` is required in the implementation.

Comment: @hexturtle I suggest you read the text of the question, looks like the functions are understood quite well and the requirement is to use `execlp()`. While being idiotic, it's actually possible, see my comment (at the cost of stupid code and limiting the maximum possible arguments)

Comment: @FelixPalmen The assignment did say that my program must handle up to 3 arguments. I guess I can use this as the maximum number of args and use your suggestion.

Comment: You could also: `if(number_of_arguments == 0) {execlp(program, program, NULL);} else if(number_of_arguments == 1) {execlp(program, program, first_arg, NULL);} else if(number_of_arguments == 2) {execlp(program, program, first_arg, second_arg, NULL);}` etc...